# Prefix list BGP 0.0.0.0/0 and 0.0.0.0/ le 32

Tags: prefix

What is the difference between "ip prefix-list out seq 10 permit 0.0.0.0/0 and ip prefix-list out seq 10 permit 0.0.0.0/0 le 32?"

Comment: LE - Less Than
GE - Greater Than. The rest of sentence is obvious I believe.

Comment: LE = Less equal, GE = Greater Equal

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

`ip prefix-list out seq 10 permit 0.0.0.0/0` will match only a default route (`0.0.0.0/0`) whereas `ip prefix-list out seq 10 permit 0.0.0.0/0 le 32` will match anything thats within `0.0.0.0/0` with a prefix length ranging from `/1` to `/32`, e.g. everything.